# BufferedReader terminating by HTTPClient

Tags: java, android, http

So I have a server and a client.

The server sends as follow

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException        
   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   resp.setContentType("text/plain");

      DO A LOT OF THINGS AND WRITE IT INTO ONE JSONARRAY

   builder.append(JsonArray.toString());
   resp.getWriter().println(builder);
}
```

and the client receives as follow:

```
 private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String output = null;
        for (String url : urls) {
            output = getOutputFromUrl(url);
        }
        return output;
    }

    private String getOutputFromUrl(String url) {
        String output = null;
        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            InputStream in = httpEntity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                builder.append(line + "\n");
            }
            Log.i("Test", builder.toString());
            in.close();

            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return output;
    }
```

The client gets the datas from a async task.

The problem is that the client receives not the whole send from the server. I tried to make a reader.read(), but there is the same problem.

If I try to get the code over a browser, I receive all datas from the server, but in my java application I do not.
So the server is completly correct, maybe I could change the jsonarray and add a \n after each jsonobject.

Could there be a problem with logcat, because it has a problem with the string, because the string is too long?

Thanks for your help.

EDIT:
CLOSED
[After HTTP GET request, the resulting string is cut-off - content has been consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744110/after-http-get-request-the-resulting-string-is-cut-off-content-has-been-consu)

Comment: Have you tried logging the end of the received string? In order to eliminate your LogCat as a source of possible error? Also, you really should use [`EntityUtils`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html) to read your HTTP response data, its an efficient one-liner of code.

Comment: I tried to get the end of file, and the BufferedReader returned null, so it ended!

Comment: If I receive with the java programme, I got 4063 Bytes and it ends. With the browser I receive the whole data with 5582 Bytes

Comment: You might want to try flushing your server side writer. Also, did you try the `EntityUtils` class for reading on the client side?

Comment: Now I flush the server and tried EntityUtils, but the problem is still exist.

Also I tried to put some \n into the builder, but the effect was the same. So the LogCat is able to show a lot of bytes!

Comment: 5582 is also the length of the json array print that gives the server out before he writes!

Comment: I tried to put a '\n' into the string of the server. Now the client reads till the each '\n' and gives it out, but the data is still incomplete!

Comment: Quite odd, could be a character encoding issue (though that would be surprising). Are you overriding the default on either side?

Comment: No. I dont change the default. 
I tried to receive the message from the server over a HTTPURLConnection but there was no effect.

Comment: Also I tried to do it on a real phone and an emulator, but both didnt get the whole data

Answer (score 1):

in method "getOutputFromUrl" nothing is assigned to "output"

Comment: Yeah right, but I dont need the output, I try to give the data in  the LogCat. The output is for the onPostExecute in the AsyncTask

Comment: try putting Log.i after in.close(). Closing the stream also flushes it. Although it would be somewhat cleaner to gracefully close the stream (try - catch - finally)

Answer (score 0):

```
   resp.getWriter().println(builder);
```

Flush your response writer and close it to ensure that the entire string is written to the socket consistently. Also, assign the value of output before returning it.

Comment: I flush it, but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

The Stringbuilder had all, but the LogCat cant display this.

[After HTTP GET request, the resulting string is cut-off - content has been consumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2744110/after-http-get-request-the-resulting-string-is-cut-off-content-has-been-consu)

This is the same problem.

So to display the stringbuilder in the LogCat I made substrings.

```
builder.substring(0,4000);
builder.substring(0,builder.length());
```

Thanks for your Help!